# Branching a C# project

Tags: c#, github

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022 with GitHub. I needed to update a Windows Forms app so I cloned the repository and made a new branch to try out my mods. When I looked at the actual form involved, all the controls were present but the size properties had been lost. Is this usual or could I have done something to retain the size properties?

Comment: Git as a versioning software is more or less content-agnostic with regards to the text file contents. There should never be a case where such actions like branching removes information that is encoded as text in the file, like the size properties of a WinForms control. Is the repository open source and available for us to clone and test ourselves?

Comment: where are the size properties stored?  if it's in something like a local.settings.json it may have been included in the .gitignore, in which case you'll need to manually add them to your own settings.  I don't know if this is your problem, but if it is then you can always right click on the project and select "Manage User Secrets" and add your settings there.  Those will only run on your local machine and will not modify the repo.

Comment: Also LWChris is right.  Git does not remove, add, or modify any source file contents when branching

Comment: Usually, control properties are generated code in the `.Designer.cs` file, e.g. lines such as `comboBox1.Size = new Size(121, 23);`. These lines are also "in the middle" of the file. So unless this is some kind of checkout-related encoding or newline issue, I would not know how Git could mess with those. And both of these options seem unlikely, as I doubt the designer would open at all if it was indeed an encoding or newline issue.

Comment: @user3017691 Have you already tried closing VS and opening the project again? A silent crash of the WinForms designer seems more likely than anything else at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry guys this is a non-question.  Everything was included correctly, it was just a change of display hardware that messed up the form's appearance.  Doh!